# How to invoke a new line after each text in the value section for embed

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am coding the help command for my discord bot and it looks good when finished but its just not perfect, I just want to know, is there a way to invoke a new line after each text in the value section for embed, for example it would look like this:

- Moderation:
- kick
- ban
- ect..

But instead it comes out as this:

- Moderation:
- kick
- ban
- ect..

and it looks so ugly, does anyone know how to accomplish this?
Here is the code that I want to make work:

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 3, commands.BucketType.channel)
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Help", description="Here are all the available commands:")
    embed.add_field(name='Moderation', value='command1, command2, command3')
    embed.add_field(name='Fun', value='command1, command2, command3')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set value to a string with newlines.

`value='command1,\ncommand2,\ncommand3'` or

```py
value="""command1,
command2,
command3"""
```